# How to Merge array in one array using PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

I have a problem When I want To rebuild my array .
this is I am create on phpfiddle.org

http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/tzp-t1u

anyone can give me suggestion ?

Comment: You may need to provide a little more information;
- what are the rules around merging the arrays (is there a common key, is there a value that match?)
- are there always just 3 indexes to start with, etc.

Comment: you would have to iterate throw the array. Array merge doesn't merge values of existing keys. it just mergers two array together and leaves duplicate keys untouched

Comment: Post your array generating code with few sample array, I really can't get what is your output & what you want it to be.

Comment: I am updated my question

Comment: What is your matching criteria for the arrays, how do you group the child key?

Comment: the array will be generate if lev4 is same , so that have a child

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will help you

```
<?php

$result = array (
        array(
                'lev1'=> null,
                'lev2'=> 34,
                'lev3'=> 21,
                'lev4'=> 22,
                'child' => 'cyaiooo'
        ),
        array(
                'lev1'=> null,
                'lev2'=> 34,
                'lev3'=> 10,
                'lev4'=> 8,
                'child' => 'test1'
        ),
        array(
                'lev1'=> null,
                'lev2'=> 34,
                'lev3'=> 21,
                'lev4'=> 22,
                'child' => 'hodem'
        )
);

$data = array();

foreach($result as $value)
{
    if(count($data)==0)
    {
        $data[] = $value;

    }else{

        foreach($data as &$container)
        {
            if($value['lev1']==$container['lev1']
                    &&
                $value['lev2']==$container['lev2']
                    &&
                $value['lev3']==$container['lev3']
                    &&
                $value['lev4']==$container['lev4'])
            {               

                if(is_string($container['child']))
                {
                    //get the string value
                    $string = $container['child'];

                    //unset the child string
                    unset($container['child']);

                    //declatre the array
                    $container['child'] = array();

                    $container['child'][] =  $string;
                }

                $container['child'][] =  $value['child'];

                break;

            }else{
                $data[] = $value;
                break;
            }
        }

    }
}

print_r($data);
```

Comment: that for your answer really I am appreciate, that are really almost like i want, but the value of children result as string, in my goal the value is array .

Comment: @viyancs you can try little to achieve the result. Anyway I modified please check the updated answer